# How to update the hardware vendor name and hardware model displayed by hostnamectl

Tags: 22.04

I build my own computer systems from scratch and then load the latest version of Ubuntu Linux... how do I change the Hardware Vendor and Hardware Model information displayed by the hostnamectl command?